# List packages in devtoolset

Tags: rhel, package-management, scl

Using `Linux 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 19 12:09:25 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

I mean to get all packages in a devtoolset (or any other `scl`, actually).
I tried (1)

```
$ scl -l devtoolset-6
```

which gives an empty output.

**A. Shouldn't this give the output that I want?**

**B. If not, what is the right command?**

As an evidence that there are packages in `devtoolset-6` (and they are actually enabled with `source /opt/rh/devtoolset-6/enable`) (2)

```
$ yum list devtoolset-6\*
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
*Note* Red Hat Network repositories are not listed below. You must run this command as root to access RHN repositories.
Installed Packages
devtoolset-6-binutils.x86_64                        2.27-10.el6.1                @/devtoolset-6-binutils-2.27-10.el6.1.x86_64
devtoolset-6-gcc.x86_64                             6.3.1-3.1.el6                @/devtoolset-6-gcc-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
devtoolset-6-gcc-c++.x86_64                         6.3.1-3.1.el6                @/devtoolset-6-gcc-c++-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
devtoolset-6-gcc-gdb-plugin.x86_64                  6.3.1-3.1.el6                @/devtoolset-6-gcc-gdb-plugin-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
devtoolset-6-gcc-gfortran.x86_64                    6.3.1-3.1.el6                @/devtoolset-6-gcc-gfortran-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
devtoolset-6-gcc-plugin-devel.x86_64                6.3.1-3.1.el6                @/devtoolset-6-gcc-plugin-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
devtoolset-6-gdb.x86_64                             7.12.1-47.el6                @/devtoolset-6-gdb-7.12.1-47.el6.x86_64
devtoolset-6-libquadmath-devel.x86_64               6.3.1-3.1.el6                @/devtoolset-6-libquadmath-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
devtoolset-6-libstdc++-devel.x86_64                 6.3.1-3.1.el6                @/devtoolset-6-libstdc++-devel-6.3.1-3.1.el6.x86_64
devtoolset-6-runtime.x86_64                         6.0-6.el6                    @/devtoolset-6-runtime-6.0-6.el6.x86_64
```

---

**EDIT**: Related questions that may help answering the main one.

1. Do all packages in a given `scl` (here, `devtoolset-6`) have to have a name starting with `devtoolset-6`?
2. Do all pckages with a name starting with `devtoolset-6` belong to that package?

Only if the answer to these two extra questions is YES (and I guess this is not true), command (2) above provides an answer to question B.
Still, I wonder about question A.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question, or what's missing?

Comment: @JeffSchaller - I wouldn't be sure, but I guess I did not answer my own question. In the edited question I explain why.